# How implement the interface in lua?

Tags: c, lua

For example, I have a.lua, b.lua, c.lua. They have many of same code,and they are running **in different lua VM**. So I want to implement a common module that contain the same code of a,b,c.

The question as below:

1.if a,b,c have the same variable v_status, and the v_status's value scope is certain. for example, the value are:

```
STAT_NULL = 1
STAT_ACTIVE = 2
STAT_INACTIVE = 3
```

I think I have two ways to implement the common module

**the first way is:**

```
--common.lua
local common = {}
local v_status = STAT_NULL

function common.set_status(st)
    v_status = st
end

function common .get_status()
    return v_status
end

return common
```

in a, b, c, I require the "common" module

```
local common = require "common"
```

if I want to set/get the status, I can do these:

```
common.set_status(STAT_ACTIVE)
local status = common.get_status()
```

==================================================================================

**the second way is:**

```
local common = {}

function common:set_status(st)
    self.v_status = st
end

function common:get_status()
    return self.v_status
end

return common
```

in a, b, c, I can call these functions as below:

```
local common = require "common"

common:set_status(STAT_ACTIVE)
local status = common:get_status()
```

I want to know which one is correct. Maybe they are all wrong. Please show me the right way to do it.
I'm a newbie in lua, I want to implement this function as lua's style instead of c/c++.
thanks very much!!!

Comment: Both of those are correct. The distinction is just whether `common` is an "object" or not. If it makes sense to think about the common module as a singleton object then it makes sense to use `:`. If it doesn't, for whatever reason, then using `.` is likely better. That said, I'm not sure why, for this example usage, a module would make sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the value to be shared across many VMs, the only way to do this is through host support (C-side). Export getter and setter functions to each VM, that will operate on the same `static int v_status` in C source. If Lua VMs are on separate threads, use access synchronization.

Modules can't solve your task, "common" will not be shared for different VMs.